# Creating new column based on the minimum of multiple existing columns with multiple conditions

Tags: conditional-statements

how can I create newvar based on the following conditions:
- newvar = the minimum of (var1, var2, var3, var4)
only if
- var1 and (var2 or var3 or var4) is not missing
- otherwise newvar = NA

Example below, newvar_want is what I want, newvar_get is what I get

[image: var1 var2 var3 var4 newvar_want newvar_get 1 6 5 3 1 TRUE NA 4 NA 2 NA TRUE 3 NA NA 1 1 TRUE 2 5 7 NA 2 TRUE 4 NA 2 7 2 TRUE]